# Generate new table with data from old table, multiplied by lookup value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, ddl, self-join

In MySQL, having these two queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `value001` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `value002` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `value003` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO country (name, value001, value002, value003) VALUES('Bulgaria', 100, 200, 300),('Portugal', 5, 6, 7),('Belarus', 20, 30, 40);

CREATE TABLE `exchange-rate`(
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `exchange-rate` (name, rate) VALUES('Bulgaria', 1.9),('Portugal', 1.1),('Belarus', 10);
```

I get the following tables:

[image]
[image]

My idea is to create a third table, where the values from the first table will be multiplied by the values for the second one. E.g., for Belarus and Portugal it will look like this:

| name | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Belarus | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| Portugal | 5.5 | 6.6 | 7.7 |

What have I done so far?

```
drop table if exists new_country;
create table if not exists new_country;
select c.*
from country c
left outer join --or something wiser?
(
--probably something is to be written here
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `create table as select` syntax, and join on the country name:

```
DROP TABLE IF exists new_country;
CREATE TABLE new_country AS
SELECT c.name AS name, 
       value001 * er.rate AS value1,
       value002 * er.rate AS value2,
       value003 * er.rate AS value3
FROM   test.country c
JOIN   `exchange-rate` er ON c.name = er.name;
```